# C# - How can I write a static function which would return a Movie object

Tags: c#, .net

I have had a lot of trouble with this most likely simple problem.
I have a movie class which has a name attribute. I want to create a static function which returns the movie instance that has that name.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public static Movie getMovieByName(string name)
{
    if(this.name == name)
    {
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidMovieException(name);
    }
}

class InvalidMovieException : System.Exception
{
    public InvalidMovieException(string value) : base(String.Format("This movie doesn't exist! Value: {0}", value)) { }
}
```

I am getting an error that I cannot use the keyword 'this' in a static method. I understand that but I still need this method to be static.
I hope someone can help me with my project :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This shouldn't be static, you're saying there can only be one movie in the world? Anyway, you need to have a static copy of a Movie, then reference that, not using "this".

Comment: I think you are looking for a `Dictionary<string,Movie>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store created Movie instances and then iterate through them.
You can do this like:

```
public static List movies;

public static Movie getMovieByName(string name)
{
    foreach(Movie m in movies)
    {
        if(m.name == name)
            return m;
    }

    throw new InvalidMovieException(name);
}
```

To create a Movie instance you can add it to the `movies` list, either on creation or on Movie constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, logically, what would `this` refer to in a `static` member?  Consider how you'd invoke this member:

```
Movie.getMovieByName("Highlander")
```

What would `this` be?  You're not operating in the context of an instance of `Movie`, so there *is no* `this`.

So what are you *actually* trying to return?  If you want to compare the string value with the names of `Movie` objects, then you need to get those names of `Movie` objects.

As an example, suppose you have some database repository of `Movie`s somewhere.  You might have a structure like this:

```
public static Movie getMovieByName(string name)
{
    var movie = MovieRepository.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.name == name);
    if(movie != null)
    {
        return movie;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidMovieException(name);
    }
}
```

Basically you'd be finding the movie from the list of movies.  Currently in your method you have nothing to compare it to, you just have the string which was passed to the method.